# PuTTY ssh tunnel through a range of ip addresses

Tags: networking, ssh, printer, putty, tunnel

okay this is a dumb question but, is there any way to tunnel multiple ip addresses through a port in a ssh tunnel?

the scenario is the following: i have two POS lan printers (192.168.0.114-115), connected to a web app hosted in cloud, ideally i would forward the port in the router and voilá, but my isp have me on proxy so thats not a posibility.

i was able to forward the ports through putty tunneling, but now i have the problem of only being able to use 1 printer.

[tunnel setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ncXN.jpg)

(the easiest thing to do would be to set up the other printer with another port, and tunnel that one as well, but this is not possible with this printer)

now from server side i can use my printer [as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhaiG.png) but im still in the trouble i can only use one (both printers print the same, at the same time so its no problem to be called within the same port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forwarding ports at the ends do not have to be the same.

So you can forward port 9101 to port 9100.

Comment: wish i could give you points, but the answers was useful, thanks!